# CasperJS not finding link when queryselector is passed a variable

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to scrape a web page with casperjs.  It's failing to click on a link when I pass the link ID as a variable, but when I manually put in the text string, it works.

This works fine

```
console.log(this.evaluate( function() {document.querySelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Name_Reports1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_dgReports_ctl03_View").click(); } ));
```

This fails to click the link

```
var id = "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Name_Reports1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_dgReports_ctl03_View";
console.log(this.evaluate( function() {document.querySelector(id).click(); } ));
```

Everything is exactly the same, except that I'm using a variable in the second item.

For completeness, here's the full function with the variable method commented out

```
casper.then(function () {
    //var id = "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Name_Reports1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_dgReports_ctl03_View";
    //console.log(this.evaluate( function() {document.querySelector(id).click(); } ));
    console.log(this.evaluate( function() {document.querySelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Name_Reports1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_dgReports_ctl03_View").click(); } ));
    console.log("Clicked: " + id);
});
```

And here's the element I'm looking for

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Name_Reports1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_dgReports_ctl03_View" class="lblentrylink" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Name_Reports1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$dgReports$ctl03$View','')">View Report</a>
```

Comment: Try passing `id` as an argument to the function (you'll need to declare the argument and then pass it in the call). Remember that the function is evaluated in a different context.

Comment: @jcaron What do you mean by that?  I'm not that familiar with JS.  If I use `console.log(this.evaluate( function(id) {document.querySelector("#" + id).click(); } ));` it still fails.

Comment: You still need to pass `id` as an argument to `evaluate`.

Comment: @jcaron Like this?  `console.log(this.evaluate( function(id) {document.querySelector("#" + id).click(); }, id ));` ?  That still doesn't work for me.

Comment: In your original post you had the `#` in the id, make sure you don't have it twice. Also try to log `id` inside the function.

Comment: @jcaron That was the issue.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @Jeff if you got your problem solved, it's nice to ask people helped you in the comments to post an answer with the solution and then accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your argument to [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) using the following method:

```
casper.then(function () {
  var id = '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Name_Reports1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_dgReports_ctl03_View';

  this.evaluate(function (id) {
    document.querySelector(id).click();
  }, id);

  console.log('Clicked: ' + id);
});
```